# Node.js to c# converting

Tags: c#, node.js

I have this function is Node.js

```
// @param {BigInteger} checksum
// @returns {Uint8Array}

function checksumToUintArray(checksum) {
  var result = new Uint8Array(8);
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    result[7 - i] = checksum.and(31).toJSNumber();
    checksum = checksum.shiftRight(5);
  }
  return result;
}
```

What would be the equivalent in c#?

I'm thinking:

```
    public static uint[] ChecksumToUintArray(long checksum)
    {
        var result = new uint[8];
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        {
            result[7 - i] = (uint)(checksum & 31);
            checksum = checksum >> 5;         
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But I'm no sure.
My main dilemma is the "BigInteger" type (but not only).
Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: You should at least return `uint[]` or rename the method.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, Yes you are correct, I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UInt8` is "unsigned 8-bit integer". In C# that's `byte`, because `uint` is "unsigned 32-bit integer". So `UInt8Array` is `byte[]`.

Javascript `BigInteger` corresponds to C# `BigInteger` (from `System.Numerics` dll or nuget package), not to `long`. In some cases, `long` might be enough. For example, if `BigInteger` in javascript algorithm is used only because there is no such thing as 64bit integer in javascript - then it's fine to replace it with `long` in C#. But in general, without any additional information about expected ranges - range of javascript `BigInteger` is much bigger than range of C# `long`.

Knowing that, your method becomes:

```
public static byte[] ChecksumToUintArray(BigInteger checksum) {
    var result = new byte[8];
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        result[7 - i] = (byte) (checksum & 31);
        checksum = checksum >> 5;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. is the js BigInteger signed?

Comment: There are several implementations of big integer in javascript. Mist popular has constructor argument as I remember, with which you can control whether it is signed or not.